# Panorama global registration

Tags: linear-systems, linear-algebra, stitching, panorama

I'm trying to do global registration algorithm for panorama like described 
[here](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2000/ee368/projects2000/project13/global.html). But I don't understand how they deal with false pairs.

Also if expand the system

u1*I*P1=u1*I => P1=I

u2*I*P2=u2*A21*P1 =>P2=A21*P1

u(i) coefficients are reduced? Or I interpret system of equations wrong?

[image]

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Can you expand the answer so that it is more self-contained? Yes it looks like the $\mu_{i}$ coefficients are reduced, at least it makes sense from the picture.